# get past events through the graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I can't seem to be able to access past events in the graph api, it only seems to give me access to the current events, either the events API is broken, or facebook does not provide access to past events, but there is nothing in the docs that would suggest that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Facebook pagination is broken for events, but there is a walk around by setting the "since" parameter to 0 and paginating upwards ans oppose to backwards...

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having a similar problem. There is a workaround using FQL, though it will only display current events and past events from the last 2 weeks.
>
> Example Query:
>
> SELECT name, pic_small, eid from event WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())

You need to set "start_time" condition in your query.Works for me.

FQL example that retrieves current & past events :

`SELECT name FROM event WHERE eid in (
   SELECT eid FROM event_member 
   WHERE uid = {you page or user id here} 
   AND start_time > '2001-11-02T12:35:00+0200'
)`

Since FQL doesn't support ( Select * ), address FQL manual to query more fields https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem. There is a workaround using FQL, though it will only display current events and past events from the last 2 weeks.

Example Query:

`SELECT name, pic_small, eid from event WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())`